# Android Studio, no puedo mostrar un texto pdf por pantalla

Tags: java, android-studio, pdf

Estoy intentando cargar un pdf, luego posteriormente mostrar pon pantalla parte del texto (las primeras 1000 palabras en este momento). El programa se carga , me deja seleccionar el pdf, clico sobre el y pasa a pantalla en blanco y ahí se queda. Como contexto estoy intentado hacer un miniproyecto de lectura ágil, el tema es cargar un pdf, posteriormente dentro de un recuadro ( que todavía no está hecho), se empezará a mostrar, hay una función para resaltar las palabras y poder seguirlas, ahora mismo debería mostrar las primeras 1000 palabras.

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import com.tom_roush.pdfbox.android.PDFBoxResourceLoader;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.net.Uri;


public class TextDisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_display2);

    PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(getApplicationContext());

    TextView tvPdfText = findViewById(R.id.tvPdfText);
    ScrollView scrollView =findViewById(R.id.my_scroll_view);

    String pdfFilePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("pdfFilePath");
    Uri pdfUri = Uri.parse(pdfFilePath);

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pdfUri);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String fullText = pdfStripper.getText(document);
       // String text = "PDF Cargado. Número de páginas: " + document.getNumberOfPages();
        document.close();
        String partialText = fullText.substring(0, Math.min(fullText.length(), 1000));
        tvPdfText.setText(partialText);
       highlightText(tvPdfText, partialText, scrollView); // Llamar a la función para resaltar el texto

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        tvPdfText.setText("Error al cargar el PDF: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void highlightText(TextView textView, String text, ScrollView scrollView) {
    final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 500; // Tiempo en milisegundos entre cada palabra resaltada

    String[] words = text.split("\\s+"); // Dividir el texto en palabras
    AtomicInteger wordIndex = new AtomicInteger(0); // Índice actual de la palabra

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int index = wordIndex.getAndIncrement();
            if (index < words.length) {
                int startIndex = spannableString.toString().indexOf(words[index]);
                int endIndex = startIndex + words[index].length();

                // Verificar y corregir los índices si hay múltiples ocurrencias de la palabra
                if(index > 0) {
                    int prevEndIndex = spannableString.toString().indexOf(words[index - 1]) + words[index - 1].length();
                    startIndex = spannableString.toString().indexOf(words[index], prevEndIndex);
                    endIndex = startIndex + words[index].length();
                }

                if (startIndex < 0) return; // Palabra no encontrada, salimos de la ejecución

                // Limpiar resaltados anteriores
                BackgroundColorSpan[] backgroundSpans = spannableString.getSpans(0, spannableString.length(), BackgroundColorSpan.class);
                for (BackgroundColorSpan span : backgroundSpans) {
                    spannableString.removeSpan(span);
                }

                // Aplicar el nuevo resaltado
                spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                // Actualizar el TextView
                textView.setText(spannableString);

                // Desplazar la vista para que la palabra resaltada sea visible
                Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
                if (layout != null) {
                    int line = layout.getLineForOffset(startIndex);
                    int y = layout.getLineTop(line);
                    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, y);
                }

                // Programar la siguiente palabra
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }
    };

    // Iniciar el ciclo de resaltado
    handler.post(runnable);
}
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PICK_PDF_FILE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPDF).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PDF_FILE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        String pdfFilePath = data.getDataString();

        Log.d("PDFPath", "PDF Path: " + pdfFilePath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TextDisplayActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("pdfFilePath", data.getDataString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/my_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPdfText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectPDF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select PDF" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Esta parte me la imprime bien:

```
// String text = "PDF Cargado. Número de páginas: " + document.getNumberOfPages();
```

contabiliza correctamente las páginas, no sé si será problema de cómo tengo los xml o qué, gracias de antemano!